# can read xml file from isolated storage

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, linq-to-xml

It's a Silverlight WindowsPhone Project and I'm trying to create a xml file in the isolatedstorage then I try to read from it, here is the code:

```
using (var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (var stream = file.OpenFile("MainLBItems.xml", FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        XDocument MainLBItems = new XDocument(
                            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                            new XComment("This is a comment"),
                            new XElement("Items")
                        );                        
                        MainLBItems.Save(stream);                        
                    }
                }
```

The problem is that when I try to read from it and here is the code

```
using (var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (var stream = file.OpenFile("MainLBItems.xml", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    XDocument MainLBItems = XDocument.Load(stream);
                    ...
                }
            }
```

I have an error telling "Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 3, position 12."
and throwing an unhandled XmlException

Could you please help me resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

I tried to add the XML Declaration separately but it didn't work too:

```
using (var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (var stream = file.OpenFile("MainLBItems.xml", FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        XDocument MainLBItems = new XDocument();
                        MainLBItems.Declaration=  new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes");
                        MainLBItems.Add(
                            new XComment("This is a comment"),
                            new XElement("Items")
                        );                        
                        MainLBItems.Save(stream);                        
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Exactly that s what the file contains , actually when I try to know what the file may contain by using run to cursor , I got only this

<!-- This is a comment--> 
<Items />

Comment: @Slaks is right: what does the file actually contain?

Comment: means that the Xdeclaration that I added doesn't fegure in the file

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't posted the XML, I can only take a guess... I have usually struck this problem when I don't have a root node in the document:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" xmlns:myNamespace="...">
<MyNodes>
    .... etc ....
</MyNodes>
```

Comment: The XML file is stored in the isolated storage so I can't get access to it although it contains only this:
<!-- This is a comment--> 
<Items />
though I a added a Xdeclaration before

Comment: Yeah, but as you can debug the code that has access to it, surely you can examine the contents of it and reproduce it here?

Comment: Exactly I did it an it contains this without a XDeclaration, and there is the problem :
-->  black line
-->  <!-- This is a comment-->
-->  <Items />

I can't understand why it s not saving the XDeclaration